# rewriting winston logging setup in ES6

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, winston

I'm implementing logging in my node app and after a quick search winston seemed like a good choice. However, I'm writing my app with ES6, and the configurations I found were written in ES5. I attempted to write it in ES6 myself but I'm getting an error:

> SyntaxError: /Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/node/bonfire-es6/bonfire/custom-modules/logging/logger.js: Unexpected token (26:13)
>
> ```
>  es7 property initializers
>   */
>   transports = [ // <--- ***************LINE #26*******************
>     new (winston.transports.Console)({son: false, timestamp: true}),
>     new winston.transports.File({ 
>       filename: __dirname + '/debug.log',
> ```

the full configuration (ES6):

```
import winston from 'winston'

export default class Logger extends winston.Logger {
  /*
    es7 property initializers
  */
  transports = [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({son: false, timestamp: true}),
    new winston.transports.File({ 
      filename: __dirname + '/debug.log', 
      json: false 
    })
  ];

  exceptionHandlers = [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({ json: false, timestamp: true }),
    new winston.transports.File({ 
      filename: __dirname + '/exceptions.log', 
      json: false 
    })
  ];

  exitOnError = false;
}
```

and the one I found online (ES5):

```
var winston = require('winston');

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({ json: false, timestamp: true }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: __dirname + '/debug.log', json: false })
  ],
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)({ json: false, timestamp: true }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: __dirname + '/exceptions.log', json: false })
  ],
  exitOnError: false
});

module.exports = logger;
```

how can I write the configuration with correct ES6?

***update*** **********************************************************

so I changed my code to this:

```
import winston from 'winston'

export default class Logger extends winston.Logger {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.transports = [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({son: false, timestamp: true}),
        new winston.transports.File({ 
          filename: __dirname + '/debug.log', 
          json: false 
        })
    ];

    this.exceptionHandlers = [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({ json: false, timestamp: true }),
        new winston.transports.File({ 
          filename: __dirname + '/exceptions.log', 
          json: false 
        })
    ];

    this.exitOnError = false;

  }
}
```

and I'm using the logger in my index.js file:

```
import Logger from '../custom-modules/logging/logger.js'
Logger.info('log to file');
```

now I'm getting this error:

> _logger2.default.info('log to file');
>                    ^
>
> TypeError: _logger2.default.info is not a function
>
> at Object. (index.js:8:8)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
>
> at loader (/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/node/bonfire-es6/bonfire/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:126:5)
>
> at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/node/bonfire-es6/bonfire/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:136:7)
>
> at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
>
> at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
>
> at require (module.js:385:17)
>
> at Object. (/Users/abdulahmad/Desktop/node/bonfire-es6/bonfire/app.js:12:14)
>
> at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)

Comment: That very comment say "*es7 property initializers*", so why are you using it when you want ES6?

Comment: @Bergi I thought I can use some ES7 stuff with ES6. I'm using the latest Babel

Comment: But you've probably not configured it to use experimental stuff (which is a good thing, actually). You need to manually enable those transformations if you want to use them.

Comment: @Bergi I see, so should I do this configuration in the constructor and assign the `transports` and `exceptionHandlers` to `'this.'`?

Comment: Yes, that's the sensible desugaring to ES6.

Comment: @Bergi please see my update

Comment: You've never instantiated the logger it seems. In the ES5 code, there is a `new`.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad - you should answer your own question, for others to get a siccinct solution and so you can get credit for the work.

Comment: @HankCa I don't think I ever did this :/